# copy procedure cell content of duplicated record_number into the empty identical duplicate

Tags: r, duplicates, copy

I have a big dataset. Basically I want to copy procedure cell content of duplicated record_number into the empty identical duplicate (as shown in the image)

```
    df<- read.table(text = 
    "record procedure
71438   hemiarch
71438   
70333   
70333   ET
73236   hemiarch
73216   ET
73246   hemiarch
73206   arch
70334   
70334   ET
", sep="\t", header=T)
```

[image]

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for a suitable duplicate (I'm sure there is one). In the meantime...

A `dplyr`/`tidyr` approach would be to use `fill` after replacing the `""` entries with `NA`s

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(procedure = na_if(procedure, "")) %>%
    fill(procedure)
#  record procedure
#1  71438  hemiarch
#2  71438  hemiarch
#3  70333  hemiarch
#4  70333  hemiarch
#5  73236  hemiarch
```

---

With your updated sample data we can fill first down then up per `record` group

```
df %>%
    mutate(procedure = na_if(procedure, "")) %>%
    group_by(record) %>%
    fill(procedure, .direction = "downup") %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 10 x 2
#   record procedure
#    <int> <fct>
# 1  71438 hemiarch
# 2  71438 hemiarch
# 3  70333 ET
# 4  70333 ET
# 5  73236 hemiarch
# 6  73216 ET
# 7  73246 hemiarch
# 8  73206 arch
# 9  70334 ET
#10  70334 ET
```

---

### Sample data

```
df<- read.table(text =
"record procedure
71438   hemiarch
71438   ''
70333   ''
70333   hemiarch
73236   hemiarch", header=T)
```

Comment: Thanks or your reply but procedure column has many categories not only"hemiarch". I am not sure how your code will identify duplicates as the first 2 observations are duplicate and the same for the second two  observations.

Comment: @MohamedRahouma `fill` fills entries from either the top down, or the bottom up (or both). Take a look at `?fill`. This seems to be exactly what you're asking based on the figure you included. You can also use `fill` within groups. Perhaps you need to provide a more representative example. Your sample data might be too simplistic.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot @MauritsEvers